# Pass method as argument to Java method

Tags: xtend

I have some java code that I want to convert to Xtend. The Java code is:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    final Canvas clock = new Canvas(parent, SWT.None);
    clock.addPaintListener(this::drawClock);
}

private void drawClock(PaintEvent e) {
    e.gc.drawArc(e.x, e.y, e.width - 1, e.height - 1, 0, 360);
}
```

My attempt at Xtend code is:

```
override createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    val clock = new Canvas(parent, SWT.None);
    clock.addPaintListener(this::drawClock);
}

private def drawClock(PaintEvent e) {
    e.gc.drawArc(e.x, e.y, e.width - 1, e.height - 1, 0, 360);
}
```

The problem is that the expression `this::drawClock` is not valid in Xtend. Specifically it says that `this` cannot be resolved to a type. How do I achieve the same result using Xtend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xtend doesn't support method references. You need to wrap the method you want to call in a Xtend lambda instead.

`this::drawClock` or `(e) -> drawClock(e)` in Java becomes `[drawClock]` in Xtend. The type is automatically inferred.

So you can write:

```
override createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    val clock = new Canvas(parent, SWT.None)
    clock.addPaintListener[drawClock]
}
```

The `PaintEvent` parameter of the listener is the implicit `it` parameter of the lambda. It is used automatically as first argument of `drawClock`. Parenthesis are optional for method calls with lambda arguments.

I would say the notation `addPaintListener[drawClock]` is the idiomatic, but you could of course also write this more explicit. All of these are equivalent:

```
clock.addPaintListener[drawClock]
clock.addPaintListener([drawClock])
clock.addPaintListener([drawClock(it)])
clock.addPaintListener([e|drawClock(e)])
clock.addPaintListener([PaintEvent e| e.drawClock])
```

If the method has multiple parameters, you can add those parameters to the lambda explicitly or use the implicit `$1,$2,...,$n` parameters, for example like this:

```
component.addFooListener[e1, e2| onFoo(e1, e2)]
component.addFooListener[onFoo($1, $2)]
```